# Can't access variable in JavaScript function scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have a situation like this:

```
console.log(someVar) // <- works, the variable is defined
var somefunction = function () {
    console.log(someVar); 
}

somefunction(); // <- someVar is undefined on the console
```

I can't demonstrate a simple model showing this because I don't even know how this is possible.  If `someVar` is defined in the context where `someFunction` is defined, isn't `someVar` also in the scope of `someFunction`?

Are there situations where it is supposed to work like this?  If so, I may have stumbled into one accidentally.

Comment: You should not be returning anything - you have no return method. You are just logging an undefined var.

Comment: "I can't demonstrate a simple model showing this because I don't even know how this is possible." — You clearly have some code which does demonstrate it. [Reduce it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) until it makes for a sensible test case.

Comment: Fine, I used the wrong word.  That's hardly relevant to the question.

Comment: @AdamHolder — Since the function actually does *return* undefined, it is quite relevant.

Comment: @Quentin Meanwhile, can anyone explain whether there is supposed to be any situation at all where this is possible?

Comment: It's a nitpicky comment.  Obviously I was talking about what is produced int he console based on the console.log function.  I'll correct it so that nobody will pretend they misunderstood.

Comment: @AdamHolder — I can think of various reasons, but I'd have thought they'd be pretty obvious, and I'm not going to speculate when you don't have a test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have a suggestion. How about not coming here, asking for help - and then responding with snarky comments when people try to help you.

Comment: I wasn't snarky to anyone who was helpful.  Or even trying to be helpful.  As usual, I was accosted by people trying to tear me down instead of offering anything helpful or constructive.  That is what happens here on StackOverflow 90% of the time.

Comment: That's fine - your question has been reported as incomplete - so you wont be getting the help you are looking for anyways. Maybe next time you could word your questions in a way that people can actually understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AdamHolder — Once again: If you provide a proper test case then people can help. If you show us code which works but claim that it doesn't work, then we can't do a lot.

Comment: The first answer of this question might explain the behavior you are seeing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/3103677

Comment: `someVar` in the scope of `someFunction` is the same as in the global scope. Since `someFunction` doesn't return a value (how EVERY function should do), it implicitly returns `undefined`. I guess you're confusing this `undefined` with the output of `console.log` within `someFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable named had been shadowed further down in the function in a non-obvious way.

Answer (score -1):

**JS**

```
var somefunction = function () {
    var somevar = "foo";
    return somevar;
}

alert(somefunction());
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arv9do3e/)

Comment: The OP has clarified that they meant the `console.log()` statement inside the function did not get the right value, not that it had anything to do with actually returning the data. In fact, they did that a good three minutes before you submitted this answer.

Comment: It is returning the proper data. OP never defined the variable in his example. The question was about scope. The solution above demonstrates how to scope his object and get something other than undefined when he checks the output.

Comment: The question shows that, while the variable is defined somewhere before the code snipped begins, it has to be defined already (because otherwise the first console.log would output undefined). So the problem is not that it isn't defined.

Comment: Thus the problem with not providing sufficient source and not wording the question properly. OP gets incomplete or bad answers.

Comment: In theory they should get close votes instead of bad answers.

Comment: I don't disagree with that.